# cannot find assembly responsible for the function ODataConventionModelBuilder

Tags: c#, odata, .net-assembly

I seem to not to be able to find the assembly

System.Web.OData

Which I need to for the function [`ODataConventionModelBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/jj890558(v=vs.118))

I am trying to make a WebAPI for my OData service, for which a [tutorial](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/) seem to link at this function, but cannot find the assembly which should have it.

Why though?

Comment: your link, literally, on 2nd line is stating that this should be in `System.Web.Http.OData.dll` assembly

Comment: `system.web.http.odata` does not exist...

Comment: And the tutorials don't indicate that assembly but using System.Web.OData.Builder;
 as shown here :http://www.odata.org/blog/how-to-use-web-api-odata-to-build-an-odata-v4-service-without-entity-framework/

Comment: Tutorial says: "In the Nuget Package Manager, install **Microsoft.AspNet.OData** and all it’s dependencies" an that's what I would say too.